# Capture Interactive Form Submission DateTime

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, interactive-email

I'm looking at implementing an interactive form as part of a campaign and would like to run a daily response extract via an extract file automation. Before extracting the users, I wanted to check if they had submitted the form within the last 24hrs to send the internal team only responses within the last day.

At present, I'm using a NOW() function within a hidden field but I was wondering if there was a more eloquent way of getting the users form submission date and using this as a condition within the extract automation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you're doing if it works ;).
The "simple" way of doing it would be to add a field onto the data extension collecting the form data called InsertDate (or something like that) and giving it a default value of now. Then you don't have to deal with the field at all...whenever a row is entered it will automatically set the time for you.

From the point of view of your data extract, I would run the query to be along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM [YourDataExtension] WHERE CAST([InsertDate] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
```

This will select everyone that filled out the form yesterday (based on Central Standard Time). Main reason for doing this is the results will be exact - using something like WHERE InsertDate > GETDATE()-1 could potentially miss records as the query won't run at exactly the same time each day if it is part of an automation...it'll be close, but not exact.

Comment: Ahh, that's a great point! Thanks for that, Jarrett and for the query above. I'm populating form data back into the send DE via the interactive form and a CloudPages landing page (for SMS recipients). I'm guessing it won't update the date column when the responses are captured in the DE?

Comment: @BenjaminPenketh - Yes, you're correct. If you're going back into the sending DE the row is already created so it won't set that value on update. In that case (and without getting into writing AMPscript - I assume you prefer not to do that given you're using Interactive Forms), what you're doing is the simplest option.